# Meaning of declaration of Memory map in flattened device tree

Tags: memory, device-tree

I have declaration for memory map as follows:

```
memory@40000000 {
    device_type = "memory";
    reg = <0 0x40000000 0 0x20000000>;
};

memory@200000000 {
    device_type = "memory";
    reg = <2 0x00000000 0 0x20000000>;
};
```

What is the meaning of each number in reg (base size) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two statements

```
reg = <0 0x40000000 0 0x20000000>;
reg = <2 0x00000000 0 0x20000000>;
```

mean, that a 64bit addressing scheme is used. However, each number in a device tree 'cell' represents a 32bit field. Thus, the numbers have to be read together as:

```
Addr: 0x040000000 Size: 0x020000000
Addr: 0x200000000 Size: 0x020000000
```

Thus, you have two 512MiB RAM ranges at two distinct address segments.

Please look for a declaration in your dts/dtsi file like:

```
#address-cells = <2>;
#size-cells = <2>;
```

Comment: Actually, the memory map above I declared for arm32 architecture. 
I agree on address-cells and size-cells aspect. 
I have to use an IOMMU to translate my address space from 32-bit to 40-bit addressing scheme.